# How to sort any array of a nested data structure by an item's either date related property value or key name?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, recursion, data-structures

My purpose is to get from this:

```
const grouped = [
  {
    "2022/11": [
      {
        "2022/11/30": [
          {
            "breaking-change": [
              {
                date: "2022-11-30T07:33:07.992955008Z",
                reponame: "test-repo",
                status: "breaking-change",
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        "2022/11/29": [
          {
            compatible: [
              {
                date: "2022-11-29T14:58:44+01:00",
                reponame: "test-repo",
                status: "compatible",
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    "2022/10": [
      {
        "2022/10/17": [
          {
            compatible: [
              {
                date: "2022-10-17T14:58:44+01:00",
                reponame: "test-repo",
                status: "compatible",
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

This:

```
[
  {
    "2022/10": [
      {
        "2022/10/17": [
          {
            compatible: [
              {
                date: "2022-10-17T14:58:44+01:00",
                reponame: "test-repo",
                status: "compatible",
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    "2022/11": [
      {
        "2022/11/29": [
          {
            compatible: [
              {
                date: "2022-12-17T14:58:44+01:00",
                reponame: "test-repo",
                status: "compatible",
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        "2022/11/30": [
          {
            "breaking-change": [
              {
                date: "2022-11-30T07:33:07.992955008Z",
                reponame: "test-repo",
                status: "breaking-change",
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

So:

1. "month-objects" ( the example would be the one in the parent array with `2022/11` as a key ) needs to be sorted by key(date/month) in an ascending way;
2. and also "days-objects" (the example would be the one in the first-level-children array with `2022/11/30` as a key ) needs to be sorted by key(date/month) in an ascending way;

That's what I tried:

```
const sortedGrouped = grouped.sort(function (a, b) {
  return (
    new Date(Object.keys(a)[0]).getTime() -
    new Date(Object.keys(b)[0]).getTime()
  );
});
```

That way I can only sort parents.

Tried to sort first-level children, but getting an `Invalid left-hand side in assignment expression` issue:

```
grouped.forEach((obj) => {
  Object.values(obj) = Object.values(obj).sort(function (a, b) {
    return (
      new Date(Object.keys(a)[0]).getTime() -
      new Date(Object.keys(b)[0]).getTime()
    );
  });
});
```

This one doesn't work for me either:

```
const sortByDate = arr => {
   const sorter = (a, b) => {
      return new Date(Object.keys(a)[0]).getTime() - new Date(Object.keys(b)[0]).getTime();
   };
   arr.forEach((i)=>Object.values(i).sort(sorter))
   return arr;
};
```

Comment: Both your input and your output formats seem suspect to me.  Do you have any control over that format?  Because Arrays and plain Objects with only a single property feel overblown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most generic solution has to based on a recursive approach.

Thus one does

- either

  - try to sort an array by retrieving a `Date` related value from each of its items,
  - and keep the recursion going for each item of the just sorted array,
- or

  - keep the recursion going for each value of an `object` type item.

Which directly leads to two other tasks

- a function which from each passed object tries to parse a valid `Date` instance from
- and a helper function which checks whether a passed value is a valid date.

The first mentioned of the latter two functions does so by either assuming an existing `date` property of the passed value or by going with the first validly parsed date from one of the passed value's keys.

```js
function isValidDate(date) {
  const time = date?.getTime?.() ?? Number.NaN;
  return (
    'number' === typeof time
    && !Number.isNaN(time)
  );
}
function parseDateFromItem({ date: dateTime = null, ...itemData }) {
  let date;

  // parse into a `Date` instance ...
  if (dateTime !== null) {

    // ... either directly from an available `date` key ...
    date = new Date(dateTime);
  } else {
    // ... or from the first validly parsable property name.
    Object
      .keys(itemData)
      .some(key => {
        date = new Date(key);
        return isValidDate(date);
      });
  }
  return isValidDate(date) && date || null;
}

function recursivelySortItemsAscendingByParsableDate(data) {
  if (Array.isArray(data)) {

    data
      .sort((a, b) =>
        (parseDateFromItem(a) ?? 0) - (parseDateFromItem(b) ?? 0)
      );
    data
      .forEach(recursivelySortItemsAscendingByParsableDate);

  } else if (data && 'object' === typeof data) {

    Object
      .values(data)
      .forEach(recursivelySortItemsAscendingByParsableDate);
  }
}


const sampleData = [{
  "2022/11": [{
    "2022/11/30": [{
      "breaking-change": [{
        date: "2022-11-30T07:33:07.992955008Z",
        reponame: "test-repo",
        status: "breaking-change",
      }],
    }],
  }, {
    "2022/11/29": [{
      compatible: [{
        date: "2022-11-29T14:58:44+01:00",
        reponame: "test-repo",
        status: "compatible",
      }],
    }],
  }],
}, {
  "2022/10": [{
    "2022/10/17": [{
      compatible: [{
        date: "2022-10-17T14:58:44+01:00",
        reponame: "test-repo",
        status: "compatible",
      }],
    }],
  }],
}];

recursivelySortItemsAscendingByParsableDate(sampleData);
console.log({ sampleData });


const moreSampleData = [{
  "2022/12": [{
    "2022/12/17": [{
      compatible: [{
        date: "2022-12-17T14:58:44+01:00",
        reponame: "test-repo",
        status: "compatible"
      }]
    }]
  }]
}, {
  "2021/11": [{
    "2021/11/30": [{
      compatible: [{
        date: "2021-11-30T07:33:07.992956372Z",
        reponame: "test-repo",
        status: "compatible"
      }]
    }]
  }]
}, {
  "2022/11": [{
    "2022/11/30": [{
      compatible: [{
        date: "2022-11-30T07:33:07.992956372Z",
        reponame: "test-repo",
        status: "compatible"
      }, {
        date: "2022-11-25T07:33:07.992955008Z",
        reponame: "test-repo",
        status: "compatible"
      }]
    }, {
      "breaking-change": [{
        date: "2022-11-30T07:33:07.992955008Z",
        reponame: "test-repo",
        status: "breaking-change"
      }]
    }, {
      "need-an-update": [{
        date: "2022-11-30T07:33:07.992955008Z",
        reponame: "test-repo",
        status: "need-an-update"
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    "2022/11/29": [{
      compatible: [{
        date: "2022-12-17T14:58:44+01:00",
        reponame: "test-repo",
        status: "compatible"
      }]
    }]
  }]
}];

recursivelySortItemsAscendingByParsableDate(moreSampleData);
console.log({ moreSampleData });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```